# Two Query Constraints On One Key with Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform, ios8

guys, I am trying to get all the PFUsers whose username is not included in an array (`dontShowUsers`. I also want to limit the query with the variable `name`, which gets all users whose username is equal a name the user searches. However when I do this:

```
findUsers.whereKey("username",containsString:name)
findUsers.whereKey("username",notContainedIn:dontShowUsers)
```

Every user shows. It peforms both these queries, and adds them together. I want to constrain the first `whereKey` with the second `whereKey`. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Check out https://parse.com/questions/pfquery-with-multiple-constraints-on-one-key

Comment: I already checked that out actually, I couldn't find out how to implement the search feature with the ```containsAllObjects```

Comment: Couldn't you do one query, and then filter through the results to find the ones matching the other? Alternatively could do that in cloud code. Or if the don't-show property is consistent for a user, could have a separate bool column in the user object which you could query on.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way

```
println(geoPoint)
user["location"] = geoPoint
let rejectedUsers: [String] = user["rejected"].copy() as [String]
let acceptedUsers: [String] = user["accepted"].copy() as [String]
let ignoredUsers = rejectedUsers + acceptedUsers

var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint)
query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: user.username)
query.whereKey("gender", equalTo: user["interestedIn"])
query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: ignoredUsers)
query.limit = 10
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error2: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error2 != nil {
        println(error2)
    } else {
        if objects.isEmpty {
            println("empty query")
        } else {
            for object in objects {
                self.usernames.append(object.username)
                self.userImages.append(object["image"] as NSData)
```

notice how i had to copy my user["rejected"] array from parse
then i used + to create "ignoredUsers"

then i was able to use:

query.whereKey("username", notContainedIn: ignoredUsers)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can solve this without using 2 constraints, just before you execute the query, check if *name* is in the the array, and if it's not, just execute the query.