# Swift Parse: Using a one to many array query

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

This is my code for a query to search an array containing numbers and display in the table each corresponding to the matches with taskID which will contain a single integer. My println displays (0,1,2,3,4,5,6). I am new to parse and just thought the simple containedIn would fix any issues with the array do i need to add the results to an array and convert to numbers ? any help would be appreciated been searching online but can't seem to find any solutions.

```
  override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

        // Start the query object
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Tasks")
        println( PFUser.currentUser()["taskIDs"])
       query.whereKey("taskID", containedIn:[PFUser.currentUser()["taskIDs"]])
        // Add a where clause if there is a search criteria

        query.orderByAscending("taskDetail")

        // Return the query object
        return query
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer-> [Two Query Constraints On One Key with Parse and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253733/two-query-constraints-on-one-key-with-parse-and-swift) if anyone finds themselves struggling, i was right it needed to be converted in to integer like this

```
    let tasks: [Int] =  PFUser.currentUser()["taskIDs"].copy() as [Int]
```